# Cannot set a breakpoint in gutter of Visual Studio for Javascript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug Javascript code in a C# web forms application using Visual Studio 2017 .I followed some documentation on the net,however the very first step is to set a debug point in the gutter ,when i try that i get "This is not a valid location for breakpoint" .I read that debug points can be set at declaration or return statement .So i initialized a variable in Javascript ,but still cannot put a breakpoint in Js code .I had put IE as default browser ,as i read in documentation that IE should be set as default browser for debugging Javascript.

I have also enabled Javascript debugging for (IE,Edge,Chrome ) in ,Debug>Options>General and restarted Visual Studio,but still cannot set breakpoint.